# Is "Modern C++ Design" DocumentManager design correct?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I was going through the "Modern C++ Design" book, I saw the below code explained in "8.1 The Need for Object Factories", and I have some doubts.

1. Is my understanding that, "CreateDocument()" should be overridden in a new derivedDocumentManager class each time a derivedDocument class is writen?
2. If Yes, then there will be way too many derived documentManagers and needs its own Factory method!!!
3. If No, then "CreateDocument()" should take an ID so that it can decide exactly what to create among a of objects. But this also means, each time a derivedDocument is created, he also should find the correct documentManager and update the CreateDocument() method. But we have to decide to have or not to have the a Factory of documentManagers as there can be few or many of them.

   My main doubt is whether this is a solution at all or if I am missing the point. According to the book, `CreateDocument()` is the GoF book's factory method. "CreateDocument()" creating a new derivedDocument based on an ID and lots of conditions at least makes sense. But lots of derivedDocumentManager does not make sense.

`DocumentManager` from the book,

```
class DocumentManager
{
    ...
public:
    Document* NewDocument();
private:
    virtual Document* CreateDocument() = 0;
    std::list<Document*> listOfDocs_;
};

Document* DocumentManager::NewDocument()
{
    Document* pDoc = CreateDocument();
    listOfDocs_.push_back(pDoc);
    ...
    return pDoc;
}
```

Client code:

```
Document* GraphicDocumentManager::CreateDocument()
{
    return new GraphicDocument;
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to ask this question at https://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: your question's been heavily edited to give it a different focus.  A few more points:

- You seem to be thinking that any mention of "factory" necessarily involves one concrete function accepting some input and spitting out an instance of one of many possible dynamic types based on the input.  That is just one type of factory, and not the type presented in your code.

Have a read about the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and hopefully you'll realise that's what you have.  It lets you do things like:

```
std::string compress(DocumentManager& d, const std::string& uncompressed)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Document> doc = std::make_unique(d.NewDcoument());
    doc = uncompressed;  // interpret to form document of whatever type
    return zlib::compress(d.data(), d.size());  // compress as binary blob
}
```

Here, the one `compress()` function can be called with some raw input and attempt to first create a document of the right caller-nominated type then stuff some data into it and compress it....

The factory aspect is the ability of compress to create an object without knowing the concrete type involved, as - being untemplated and lacking any switching - it can't otherwise choose between many constructors.

---

Answer based on original questions...

> Are we not moving the problem of object creation from `Document` to `DocumentManager` class. I mean we have to create [concrete] `DocumentManager`?

That's the point isn't it - to have extra record-keeping (in this case the `list<Document*>`) around the creation of specific types of `Document`s.

If we let client code create `Document`s directly, having such a list would depend on the client updating the list every time they create an object (or require invasive changes to the `Document` constructors).  If we wanted to say add timestamps for when the object creations we'd have to modify every place in the client code that creates any type of `Document`.

If we didn't have a `DocumentManager` base class, we'd have to put similar logic and data members into any number of `GraphicDocumentManager`, `TextDocumentManager`, `AudioDocumentManager` etc., and couldn't handle those managers polymorphically (e.g. creating a `vector<DocumentManager*>`, writing functions ala `void f(DocumentManager&);`.

> How to keep track of all the derived classes of `DocumentManager`, created by many independent clients?

There's nothing in the design intended to do that, and C++ doesn't have introspective facilities that would let you enumerate the derived types - neither at compile-time nor when the program starts running.  But, if you're prepared to wait for `NewDocument` to be called you could record the addresses of concrete `DocumentManager`-derived objects and/or access their RTTI information (which would e.g. let you count the distinct types of documents that had been created, or try displaying the implementation-defined (and possibly empty) `name()` field of the dynamic types....

> Should not the listOfDocs_ be static and DocumentManager be a singleton.

Probably not.  The program might want to do something like keep a `DocumentManager` object per TCP client, per filesystem, per user etc. - so why limit it unnaturally?  It's easy and better to make a more flexible `DocumentManager` type, then let client code apply a singleton wrapper (e.g. function returning a `static` instance) if that's actually useful for them.  That also makes it easier to test: you can freely create `DocumentManager`s, run a test, let destructors run, create another etc....

> My main doubt is, is that a solution at all or I am missing some point.

Seems you're missing something "bit picture", but without the book to hand or more general question/statements-of-understand from you it's hard to know what else it might be.

> According to the book "CreateDocument()" is the GoF book's factory method. But I am not able to understand the above points.

Yes - that's a factory method, as it creates any of many different dynamic types of objects, but returns a pointer-to-base-class by which they can be handled polymorphically.

Comment: I understood the need for listOfDocs_  and DocumentManager as base class. But the question i was asking is, don't we need a factory for manage all the DerivedDocumentManager? Also "CreateDocument()" should take some ID if it want to decide one of many conceit Documents. Alternatively we can override CreateDocument() for each derived Document() but then listOfDocs_  will be meaningless. I will update the question to reflect these questions.

Comment: @rakesh: *"don't we need a factory [to] manage all the DerivedDocumentManager?"* - who knows?  In any given program, some small percentage of types might be created using factories - just because there's a use for managing `Document` creation in this way doesn't say anything about the program's needs around `DocumentManager`s.  Having every object type created using a factory - just for the sake of it - would be obfuscating, verbose, inefficient and confusing.

Comment: *"Also "CreateDocument()" should take some ID if it want to decide one of many conceit Documents."* - that's not what *these* factories are doing... each creates a specific document type, so they're only useful if the calling code knows at compile time what type they want, then the type can be erased as the concrete object is handled polymorphically using the `Document*`.  Compile time knowledge of type-to-create is assumed to be had by the caller for this `Document` code.  That contrasts with factories used to take some runtime input and create one of many dynamic types of object.

Comment: *"Alternatively we can override `CreateDocument()` for each derived `[Xyz]Document[Manager]` but then `listOfDocs_` will be meaningless."* - not at all... the `listOfDocs_` is reusable functionality tracking the instances of the *particular* type of derived document.  What's useless about that?  Who's to say it's useless without understanding the client app/code's needs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are we not moving the problem of object creation from the `Document` to the `DocumentManager` class? I mean do we have to create concert `DocumentManager`? How can we keep track of all the derived classes of `DocumentManager`, created by so many independent clients?

   - `CreateDocument` is the factory method. `DocumentManager` is not responsible for creating the object. `CreateDocument` of derived manager (`GraphicDocumentManager`) will create document in its specific way.
2. Shouldn't the `listOfDocs_` be static and `DocumentManager` be a singleton?

   - Yes I think so. There can not be two manager classes ideally. But I don't know the complications with the singleton with derived classes.
3. My main doubt is whether there is a solution at all or if I am missing the point. 
      According to the book, `CreateDocument()` is the GoF book's factory method. But I am not able to understand the above points.

   - This is factory method only.

Please read this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35789/Understanding-Factory-Method-and-Abstract-Factory